# Testing Python to MySQL error

Tags: python

I have created a little script that allows me to save data to MySQLdb. At first it was working fine when I was using:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO people (name, text) VALUES ("dan", "test2")')
```

The above would save "dan" into the title and "test2" into the text. I wanted to test to see if I was able to define something and fill it in this way. For example if I was to scrape a site and say (`dan = soup.title.string`) or something like that it would be able to populate this data into the database. I have tried to have a look around but cannot seem to find anything.

```
import MySQLdb
import sys

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(
        host = 'localhost',
        user = 'root',
        passwd = '',
        db = 'python',
        )
except:
    print "db not found"

dan = "dandandan"
test2 = "testing101"

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO people (name, text) VALUES (dan, test2)')
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM people')
result = cursor.fetchall()
db.commit()
db.close()
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
C:\Users\********\Desktop>python mysqltest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysqltest.py", line 18, in <module>
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO people (name) VALUES (dan)')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defau
lterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Champ 'dan' inconnu dans field list"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prepared statements:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO people (name, text) VALUES (%s,%s)", (dan, test2))
```

From the [documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) :

> paramstyle
>
> String constant stating the type of parameter marker formatting
>   expected by the interface. Set to 'format' = ANSI C printf format
>   codes, e.g. '...WHERE name=%s'. If a mapping object is used for
>   conn.execute(), then the interface actually uses 'pyformat' = Python
>   extended format codes, e.g. '...WHERE name=%(name)s'. However, the API
>   does not presently allow the specification of more than one style in
>   paramstyle.
>
> Note that any literal percent signs in the query string passed to
>   execute() must be escaped, i.e. %%.
>
> Parameter placeholders can only be used to insert column values. They
>   can not be used for other parts of SQL, such as table names,
>   statements, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that bud, sorry if this question comes across as newbie just want to make sure I am understanding this correctly. If I am to use three rather than two the line would be: cursor.execute('INSERT INTO people (name, text) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)', (dan, test2, test3))

Comment: @BubblewrapBeast yes, you can add other parameters, the style doesn't change. Obviously parameters's order is relevant for the command execution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use parameters.

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO people (name, text) VALUES (%s,%s)', (dan, test2))
```